# OLS standard error log log regression

Tags: regression, standard-error, logarithm, power-law

I am estimating the following Power Law relationship:
$$\ln(\text{Rank}) = \text{constant} + \alpha \ln(\text{Size})$$
where $\text{Rank}$ is $1,~2,~3,~...,~n$, and $\text{Size}$ is the raw value.

What are the standard errors of the alpha coefficient in this instance? I read in an article that you cannot use the normal formula because Rank is autocorrelated (by construction) and taking logs alters some properties. If it helps, the formula I have seen for the standard error in this instance is $\text{SE}(\alpha) = \alpha (2/n)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.